# Can I drive a stepper motor with a regular MCU?

Tags: microcontroller, driver, stepper-motor

If we just focus on the signals and not the power, will an ordinary MCU like any of the ubiquitous Atmel 32-bit controllers be sufficient to drive a step motor?

What are the benefits of prepackaged special purpose motor driver chips apart from the simplified PCB layout?

Comment: How can you possibly *not focus on power*, if that's exactly what makes the difference?

Comment: The answer is yes, but current of micros is limited.  This has been asked before with very good answers...

Comment: Of course, at least with wise software design.  Stepper motors tend to require consistent pulse timing and at higher speeds/loads smooth acceleration profiles, so some care may be required especially if you are making moves involving more than one.  But even lowly ATmegas routinely run 4 or more in coordination for printers.  Ironically it is "modern" processors for multitasking systems which are generally unsuited, at least when running their ordinary software stacks or using "PC style" I/O interfaces that achieve high bandwidth at the cost of high latency.

Comment: What a *signal generating* driver chip gets you is offloading step sequencing (trivial), microstep proportioning, and potentially a current chopping comparator.  That is distinct from the *power driving* role which you said you weren't interested in talking about, though it is required for all but the tiniest high impedance indicator motors.

Comment: @Eugene: I am a beginner so I might have not understood something ,but in my understanding, in a driver for a motor there are two parts; one to generate correct signals, and one to amplify those signals to the correct amp/voltage for the motors. Is that correct? I meant focusing only on the signal generation part as opposed to the power amplification part.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: OK so what you are saying is (as I suspect Eugene is too) "YES, an MCU is good enough, but the power stuff you get in the IC is where I should focus my attention"?

Comment: A stepper is essentially a digital motor.  Supply pulses and it will rotate.  But there is a reason why drivers are used to interface micros to devices.  Power is limited.  Let the micro do the control and leave the driving to a device meant to handle it.

Comment: Frankly both signal generation and power driving are areas that need attention if you want good reliable results beyond the most relaxed use cases.

Comment: @LennartRolland: I think you understand correctly. Basic stepper sequence generation can be done in the MCU. Stepper chips offer extra functions (above a simple transistor driver solution) in the chips. These include microstepping, current control and, usually, the protection diodes.

Comment: generally no, I have played with the motors used for moving the needle on a gauge on your dash.  But, if you want to move anything heavier with a beefier motor, you will very quickly melt down your microcontroller.  At the end of the day the answer is in the datasheets for the mcu and the motor, just read them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, an ordinary MCU would be sufficient to drive a stepper motor, in a 'dumb' way.

Many special purpose stepper motor drive chips do more than generate the appropriate step sequence to energise the stepper motor coils.

So special purpose stepper motor drive chips are **not** equivalent to an MCU with some power switching.

For example, some stepper motor driver chips will drive the stepper coils with *constant current* from a higher voltage than the stepper is rated. This allows the stepper motor to achieve better performance. Using a 'dumb' stepper sequence and dumb power switching with an over-voltage power source would likely overheat and damage the stepper motor.

Also, some stepper motor driver chips will handle microstepping, which gives smoother movement, and could avoid or minimise stepper motor resonance.

Stepper motor drivers are also likely to protect the motor from excessive current draw if it stalls.

It would be possible to use a MCU, with enough resources, to achieve all of these things too. However the complexity of the electronics is well beyond power switching. Also the complexity of MCU-based software to achieve comparable performance and robustness would take a significant amount of time to develop (from scratch).

Comment: While not using a higher voltage with current regulation means that the torque rapidly falls off with speed.  However, this can be implemented by an MCU as well - it is just more often offloaded as it needs a comparator and any fault/hang in the MCU software could leave the motor receiving more than rated current which is a heating and potentially even permanent demagnetization damage issue.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - I think I've addressed your comments?

Answer (score 1):

You won't find any decent project with MCU that controls the stepper motor, because is not made for it. There are lots of dedicated stepper motor ASIC that can control current, voltage of stepper windings to work properly. 
The Atmel MCU is just too slow to control, a DSP perhaps can do it, but that would be expensive. ASICs are built of discrete components: comparators, latches, transistors, clocks, etc like L297 + L298 to newer Alllegro, ST,.. drivers. As said not a job for MCU indeed, with it you just send the setpoints: step pulses.